# How to create reusable Azure devops Yaml template not coupled to GIT

Tags: git, azure-devops, yaml

**Problem to solve**: I have my own build pipeline defined in YAML and an old task group. Task Groups are simply sets of tasks that are not tight to a repo. However YAML does not support Task Groups.

**Possible solution**: Therefore I need to create a YAML template that I can reuse in my pipeline build. This YAML template will be a "translation" of the Task Group.

**Problem of the solution**: YAML Templates (as far as I understood) are simply YAML pipelines themselves. But this means that they are coupled to GIT repos, which I don't want! I just was a reusable set of tasks that I can reference from my build pipelines.

How do I create a template not tight to a repo in Azure Devops? Is there a flaw in this solution and you suggest another approach?

Comment: why though? there is no harm in having a devops repo in azure devops with yaml files you can reuse all across your org (potentially other orgs as well).

Comment: @4c74356b41 that's a good point.. but can I reference a repo to get one specific template in there even though multiple templates are in there?

Comment: yeah, you can pick a template, obviously ;)

Comment: If your pipeline has templates in another repository, or if you want to use multi-repo checkout with a repository that requires a service connection, you must let the system know about that repository. The `repository` keyword lets you specify an external repository. Check here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/yaml-schema?view=azure-devops&tabs=schema%2Cparameter-schema#repository-resource.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As @4c74356b41 mentioned there is nothing bad to keeping coupling to git. There is no other better way than keeping YAML template than in git repo. If you have sth common across project or organization, create separate repo just for templates. And yes you can point to specific template in that repo. Please take a look [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/templates?view=azure-devops#use-other-repositories)

If you have repo `Contoso/BuildTemplates` and `common.yml' there

```yaml
# Repo: Contoso/BuildTemplates
# File: common.yml
parameters:
- name: 'vmImage'
  default: 'ubuntu 16.04'
  type: string

jobs:
- job: Build
  pool:
    vmImage: ${{ parameters.vmImage }}
  steps:
  - script: npm install
  - script: npm test
```

you can refer to this template in another repo like this:

```yaml
# Repo: Contoso/LinuxProduct
# File: azure-pipelines.yml
resources:
  repositories:
    - repository: templates
      type: github
      name: Contoso/BuildTemplates

jobs:
- template: common.yml@templates  # Template reference
```

where `common.yml` is name of the template and `templates` is alias for your repo where you keep templates.